# prove that a quartic must have 0 or 2 inflection points

Tags: calculus, polynomials, proof-writing

> Suppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $4$. Prove that $f(x)$ has either $0$ or exactly $2$ inflection points.

So I let $f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + d$ as is the convention, and found the $f''(x)$ which is $12ax^2 + 6bx + 2c$. I think $D = 9b^2 - 24ac$, and if $D>0$, there are 2 inflection points, if $D=0$ there is 1 inflection point and $D<0$ there is 0 inflection point, and I've also used the quadratic formula to get that $x = \frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9b^2 - 24ac}}{12a}$, but I don't know what to do next...

Comment: and $$f'''(x)=24ax+6b$$ must be $\neq 0$

Comment: so x must not be $-\frac{b}{4a}$, and from what I found, $x>-b/(4a)$ makes $f''(x)$ positive and $x<-b/(4a)$ negative. And $f''(x)$ should have differing signs before and after its potential inflection points, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that the second derivative can have at most $2$ roots. If $D<0$, then $f$ always has the same concavity (since $f''>0$ or $f''<0)$. So there are no inflection points in this case. If $D=0$, concavity of $f$ doesn't change at the root of the second derivative. So there are no inflection points in this case too. If $D>0$, then the sign of $f''$ will go from $+$ to $-$ to $+$; or $-,+,-$; in this case, $f$ has two inflection points.

Answer (score 0):

Saying it briefly: since polynomials are infinitely differentiable, between two critical points there is an inflection point, by [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem). Since $f'(x)$ has odd degree three, there is one critical point, or three critical points. The first situation gives us no inflection points, and the second situation gives two inflection points.